# Jasmine: How to call method having context as perameter

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am new to Jasmine, can any one help me how to call a method which having context as parameter.

```
Ex:- function locationInit(context) {
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the context parameter  need to pass while calling it in Jasmine?

Comment: A little more information about the question would be helpful answering your question better.

Comment: Hi Siddarth, I want to cover that function so I need to pass context as parameter rt? I am in diploma how to pass that context as parameter. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, ideally what I would do is debug and find all possible values `context` can assume.

After doing this, the way you write tests depends on the framework for which you're testing.

I have been testing AngularJS code so let's take angular for instance. If I have a service like the following:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.service('serviceA', function() {
  return {
    methodName: function(context) {
      return context;
    }
  }
});
```

And I want to test `methodName` from `serviceA`, something like the following would be my test case:

```js
describe('service: serviceA', function() {

  var serviceA;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_serviceA_) {
    serviceA = _serviceA_;
  }));

  describe('method: methodName', function() {
    it('should initialize some variables', function() {
      expect(serviceA).toBeDefined();
      var context = "Hello World!"
      expect(serviceA.methodName(context)).toEqual("Hello World! is the context.");
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps you understand. This was based on whatever details you provided in the question. If you need more, please provide with some more information, like what framework you're using, what is it that you want to test, is it a controller or a service etc.